# Auth0 and react will not update my login button until navigation

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I will try to put all the code involved here. I used a react tutorial to add Auth0 to my project.  It was all working fine until I started getting a syntax error around this line.

```
  const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
```

};

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token (13:26)

  11 | 
  12 |   const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
> 13 |     history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
     |                           ^
  14 |   };
```

What I did was just remove the ? and it worked. However I think that small change made my login button stop working the way it did.

So I have nav bar with Login button.  I login and it changes the button to logout. That worked.  Now I need to login then navigate to any other page in my app before the logout button shows up.  Something about triggering the router?

```
Login Button

import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

const LoginButton = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <Button
      variant="link"
      // className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
      onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}
    >
      Log In
    </Button>
  );
};

export default LoginButton;
```

Authentication button is the code that loads the button and displays some extra admin links on login and the logout button to my menu

```
const AuthenticationButton = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  return isAuthenticated ? 

    <span>
      <NavDropdown title="Admin" id="dropdown-menu-align-right">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/CreateMap">Create Map</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/EditMap">Edit Existing Map</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/Profile">User Profile Auth0</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
      <LogoutButton />
    </span>
  : <LoginButton />;
};

export default AuthenticationButton;
```

This is my Auth Provider with history class where I removed the '?'

```
const Auth0ProviderWithHistory = ({ children }) => {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;

  const history = useHistory();

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
    history.push(appState.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      useRefreshTokens={true}
      cacheLocation="localstorage"
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export default Auth0ProviderWithHistory;
```

So the code does work its just I hit login and go through SSO with Auth0 then it returns to the same page with login button still active and no admin links. Once I then navigate to any part of my site it refreshes with logout button displayed and admin link.  It used to on clicking login update the page with admin menu and logout.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed my redirect method to and it works as expected now.

```
  const onRedirectCallback = appState => {
    history.push(
      appState && appState.returnTo
        ? appState.returnTo
        : window.location.pathname
    );
  };
```